# grammar regarding "see you"

Tags: grammar

Time: 2 P.M.

Location: Hilton Hotel

Date: April 7th

Weekday: Sunday

---

What is the correct grammar?

See you 2 p.m. on Sunday, April 7th, at the Hilton Hotel.

See you on Sunday, April 7th, at 2 p.m. at the Hilton Hotel.

Comment: You missed *see you **at** 2 p.m* in the first sentence.

Comment: Didn't know "at" was needed. Is that the correct grammar? So it's: See you at 2 p.m. on Sunday, April 7th, at the Hilton Hotel...? @Jason Bassford

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's just the same as in the second sentence (that uses *at*), but the order of the time and date are reversed. (It's *at* time, *on* date, and *at* place.)